# Is the ES6 class based inheritance is same like es5 prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, es6-class, prototypal-inheritance

Behind the scene, is the ES6 class based inheritance is exactly same as es5 prototypal inheritance or not?
If not, what is the difference?
Is chrome does the same as of ES6 tranpilers, i mean internally compile the es6 classes to function constructor?

Comment: It's mostly the same. One of the differences is that you can only call an ES6 class constructor using `new`. Not using `new` is an error.

Comment: Class oriented in JavaScript is just syntactic sugar

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood it's the same implementation, "class" in Javascript is just a syntactic sugar.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

> JavaScript classes, introduced in ECMAScript 2015, are primarily syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will treat it the same if it's supports ES6 class, otherwise your code written in class based inheritance will cause an error on the browser. So one of the difference you could consider is the browser support.